# Jenkins + Kubernetes: Cannot limit number of concurrent build executor in ""Parallel"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a list of job (have more 10 jobs) then executed them in "Parallel". Besides, I also configured "Container Cap" under `Jenkins > Configuration > cloud` as 3. I expected that just 3 jobs would run at the same time and the remaining is in queue however, all jobs were executed.

However, if I dont use parallel and trigger each job manually, its behavior as expected.

Could you please let me know there is any missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the plugin, fixed in 1.12.6 https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1126